# SikuliX IDE to use dotted characters

Tags: character-encoding, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I use SikuliXIDE 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT with Ruby scripting and have strings, which contains following dotted characters: `áéöüóőúű`. I try to use `paste()` method to put it to a field.

I found solution ALT key codes, but I don't know where these characters located in string.
I found `paste(unicode())` method, but it isn't present in newest SNAPSHOT version.

Answer (score 1):

try using the below code

```
paste(myPathname.force_encoding("Windows-1252").encode("UTF-8"))
```

please refer the [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/677799) for more info

hope you get the solution....

Comment: I see, but I have to know encoding of text file to use this solution, so it is not universal.